# Finding the p-value for a Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test Difference of Paired Samples in R

Tags: r, p-value

So, I am making my own Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test function in R and am currently working finding the p-value. I have worked through how to find the test statistic and I was just wondering if there was an easy function that could find the p-value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No code in this question. Improve it or expect closure.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, I would use an index like $p.value after the function.  For instance the p.value for chi-square test can be obtained using chisq.test(x_value,y_value)$p.value.

Many statistical tests return `list` objects with each statistic of interests held within.

If you save the object you can then use `str()` to look at what's inside and call it that way.

Here's an example

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = sample(1:5,20,T), # some fake data
            y = sample(1:3,20,T))
 wilcox.test(mydata$x,mydata$y) # returns the results

wilcox.test(mydata$x,mydata$y)$p.value # returns the p_value
```

Comment: Did you check the setting of paired?